# Reviewing Firefox Extensions - When was it installed?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I wish to review my Firefox Extensions, specifically I want to know the date when I installed all my extensions. Is this possible?

I know about [Review installed extensions | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/review-installed-extensions) support article but it's not helpful.  And I know about `about:addons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Firefox Extension Tracker](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/extensionsjson.html), a one page web app, was kindly created by [Jefferson Scher](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/) in response to my questions via this [Issues post](https://github.com/jscher2000/Firefox-File-Utilities/issues/1) on his Github repo for [Session History Scrounger for Firefox (with lz4 support) — Fx File Utilities](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger_20180826.html). FireFox Extension Tracker displays for Extensions: Name and Version; installation date and updated date; Status; and ID and source. It solved all my original question but didn't solve my later wishes for sortable list but that may be in a future version.

To use:

1. Press `⊞ Win` + `R`
2. Type into the text box  `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`.
3. Select your profile (usually folder with .default)
4. Find `extensions.json`
5. Goto https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/extensionsjson.html
6. Drag and drop the previous `extensions.json` file into the Drop File Here box.
7. The information is now displayed

[image: Firefox Extension Tracker]

With thanks to [MC10](https://superuser.com/users/403203/mc10) for pointing out the keywords to search for and where to look to get more help.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming Windows here. Go to `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`. Go into your profile and then find `extensions.json`.

Each extension should have an `installDate` attribute. It will be in Epoch time (e.g. 1553267439302) so you'll want to [convert](https://www.epochconverter.com/) it to a human readable format. Also has a `defaultLocale` | `Name` attribute which has the extension name in it.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea of how to do it. It's not particularly user friendly. I viewed the ``extension.json`` in Firefox and it had a nifty expandable tree view but I couldn't work out some of the extensions. I found the id attribute but that was sometimes gobbledy gook.

Comment: Yeah I have a few of those as well. I couldn't find any listings to reconcile those. There might be a workaround you can try though. Go into the `extensions` folder and find the .xpi files with those GUID names. Drag the files into Firefox as a new tab and it should try to install those extensions, you can always cancel it. For me, they were mostly just Themes.

Comment: This is all so fiddly. I wish there was an extension or web app where we can drop the extensions.json file to find a sortable list or table with extension name and install date. Ideally this would be in the about:addons page. I am also asking on Addons.Mozilla.org forum and support.mozilla.org forum.

Comment: Kind of like [Session History Scrounger for Firefox (with lz4 support) — Fx File Utilities](https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger_20180826.html) but for ``extensions.json``